# Can a servlet filter distinguish between and filter out unauthorized POST, GET, DELETE, etc. requests?

Tags: java, rest, servlet-filters

We have some REST endpoints (e.g., /getalleuropeancars or /getalljapanesecars or /getallamericancars). These endpoints are all GET **only**.

Right now, each annotated endpoint class has its own code for checking for unauthorized methods (which is everything except GET). We would like one class to handle all unauthorized methods; you know, code re-use and all that.

Will a filter be able to distinguish between "GET /getalleuropeancars" and "POST /getalleuropeancars" and "DELETE /getalleuropeancars" and redirect to the proper place? Looking at servlet filters, it seems that they can only detect different URL paths, not different HTTP methods.

```
<url-pattern>/getalleuropeancars</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/getalljapanesecars</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/getallamericancars</url-pattern>
```

So, is a servlet-filter what we need?

Comment: The `HttpServletRequest` has a [`getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod--) method which will tell you its type.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am attempting to see if the filter can determine the HTTP method.

Comment: Yes, the filter has access to the `HttpServletRequest` on which it can invoke the `getMethod` method to check if its `GET` or anything else. If it's anything else, it can respond with 405.

Comment: But, what I am using is the web.xml forwarding to the annotated Java classes. Somebody told me that I needed a servlet filter to filter the HTTP methods, but I cannot see how the two connect.

Comment: SotiriosDelimanolis already told you (twice). You are mistaking what a filter can detect and what web.xml configuration can configure. Filter can detect the method (by using the getMethod() of the request) even if it cannot be configured in web.xml.

Comment: I believe what I am getting wrapped around the axle about is the mixing of two "different" technologies ... comparing apples to oranges, if you will; Java servlet technology vs. Java REST technology. It is difficult to see using one to aid the use of another.

Answer (score 1):

Yes a Servlet Filter can do it.  There are two things here, one is mapping the Filter to all the paths (url-patterns) you want it to filter.  Second is to have it filter out the non-GET methods.  Below is the code of a Filter that filters out non-GET requests.  Jus fill in the `//return error` with your own code for returning an error.

```
public class OnlyGetsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest sr, ServletResponse sr1, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest hsr = (HttpServletRequest) sr;
        if (!"GET".equals(hsr.getMethod())) {
            //return error
        } else {
            fc.doFilter(sr, sr1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```